# Clusters in Graphviz won't space symmetrically

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to get multiple clusters of nodes to space evenly in Graphviz.

I think the image best explains what I'm trying to do:

[image]

As you can see from the image, there is extra spacing between layers 2 and 3. The space between 2 and 3 should be the same as the space between 1 and 2.

The spacing also needs to scale with more than 3 layers. When I tried more than 3 layers, the 4th layer is spaced as bad as the 3rd layer.

Here is my graph file:

```
digraph G {
    nodesep=1.25;
    splines=false;

    node[width=1, shape=circle];
    edge[style=invis];

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label="Layer 1";
        "1-1" -> "1-2" -> "1-3";
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label="Layer 2";
        "2-1" -> "2-2" -> "2-3";
    }

    subgraph cluster_3 {
        label="Layer 3";
        "3-1" -> "3-2" -> "3-3";
    }

    edge[style=solid, penwidth=1, constraint=false];

    "1-1" -> "2-1";
    "1-3" -> "2-1";

    "1-1" -> "2-2";
    "1-2" -> "2-2";

    "1-2" -> "2-3";
    "1-3" -> "2-3";

    "2-1" -> "3-1";
    "2-3" -> "3-1";

    "2-1" -> "3-2";
    "2-2" -> "3-2";

    "2-2" -> "3-3";
    "2-3" -> "3-3";

}
```

How can I go about getting my spacing symmetrical? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Update:
I have managed to get the spacing even, but it is not a perfect solution.

By placing an invisible node with invisible edges above the graph and connecting it to the top node in each layer, the layers space evenly. However, this node messes up spacing for things that need to be added above the image shown. So, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I thik you found a bug in the layout engine. the extra space appears where an edge `"x-3" -> "y-1"` with splines would be routed around node `"y-2"`.

Comment: @stefan without a  container, there's no reason for the layout engine to assume that equal spacing matters (that's not to say it shouldn't be programmed to do so). Nesting the clusters inside another cluster causes the layout engine to space them equally. See code in my answer, below.

Comment: @benrudgers: the (absence of) reasoning with or without 'container' is the same. the equal spacing is only by accident and the big white space in the outer cluster does clearly show a problem in determining the size of the inner graph. see also my comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 2):

### Adding an Outer Cluster

[image: Correctly spaced image showing bounding box of added outer cluster]
*Bounding box of outer cluster shown for clarity*

Nesting the clusters `cluster_1`, `cluster_2`, and `cluster_3` inside another cluster causes the layout engine to space them evenly.

### Working With the Layout Engine

However, the bottom to top `rankdir` reverses the left to right display ordering to `(cluster_3, cluster_2, cluster_1)`. Reversing the order in the source file fixes [kludges over] that.

### Working Code

```
digraph G {
  nodesep=1.25;
  splines=false;
  clusterrank=local;
  node[width=1, shape=circle];
  edge[style=invis];

  subgraph cluster_0 {

    subgraph cluster_3 {
      label="Layer 3";
      "3-1" -> "3-2" -> "3-3";
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 {
      label="Layer 2";
      "2-1" -> "2-2" -> "2-3";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
      label="Layer 1";
      "1-1" -> "1-2" -> "1-3";
    }
  }

 edge[style=solid, penwidth=1, constraint=false];

 "1-1" -> "2-1";
 "1-3" -> "2-1";

 "1-1" -> "2-2";
 "1-2" -> "2-2";

  "1-2" -> "2-3";
  "1-3" -> "2-3";

  "2-1" -> {"3-1" "3-2"};
  "2-3" -> {"3-1" "3-3"};

  "2-2" -> {"3-2" "3-3"};

}
```

### Notes

The new outer cluster can be styled so that it's bounding box is not visible.

Comment: first - the outer cluster stretches the graph size which is unwanted behaviour. second - within a cluster there is absolutely no ordering of clusters. your example gives random order of clusters on my machine (win7 64bit; gv 2.38.0). results are 123 like your image, 321 with two big spacings and even a gross looking 231.

Comment: @stefan As in your question, the size of the graph is the default. The manual describes how to control the behavior. This time I'll let you read it for yourself. You're Welcome.

Comment: I did not ask any question. I did point out why I think your solution is no solution. first - your outer cluster stretches the graph size. I'm not talking of visibility but of the resuting image in pixels. If I overread a solution for that I would be glad if you point me and the OP to the point in the manual AND post a reproducible solution for the OP and all other readers. second - your 'solution' does show random behaviour. please check that. Unless this is a bug specific to my version 2.38.0 I consider your solution plain wrong and ask you to redraw your answer.

Comment: My solution is the simplest thing that solves the problem in the question. It works consistently on Linux Ubuntu 15.04. Problems with Windows should be reported to the developers. If the problem is with pixels try outputting to SVG. Documentation is available via the Graphviz website. I apologize for confusing your problems with that posed in the question.